# Questioning the validity of the method of solving Cauchy Euler ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I am given a Cauchy-Euler form second order differential equation $$x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=f(x).$$
The usual textbook method for solving the Cauchy Euler equation is to reduce it to a linear differential equation with constant coefficients by the transformation $x=e^t$. But I have a fundamental doubt here, we know that $e^t>0$ $\forall t\in \mathbb R$. But when we are using the above transformation we are subconsciously assuming $x>0$. How does this make sense?

Substituting $t=\ln(x)$ also makes no difference as $\ln$ is defined on $\mathbb R_{>0}$. So I now doubt the validity of the method followed to solve the Cauchy-Euler equation.

Can someone give me a proper explanation of what exactly going on here and why the process is valid?

Comment: General comment: I like to "try" $y(x)= x^p$ instead and solve a "characteristic equation" for $p$ (this solves the homogeneous case: roots $p_1\neq p_2$ give $c_1x^{p_1}+c_2x^{p_2}$; double root $p$ gives $c_1x^p+c_2x^p\ln x$; $p=a\pm bi$ gives $c_1x^a\cos\ln bx +c_2x^a \sin\ln bx$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler-Cauchy equation has a singularity at $x=0$. This singularity splits the domain of the ODE, which in turn limits any solution of the ODE to a sub-interval of either $x>0$ or $x<0$, depending on the initial condition. In the unusual case where the initial condition is at some negative $x_0$, you can of course also use the substitution $x=-e^t$ or more generally $x=x_0e^t$.

So with $u(t)=y(x_0e^t)$ one gets $u'(t)=y'(x_0e^t)x_0e^t=xy'(x)$ and $u''(t)=y''(x_0e^t)(x_0e^t)^2+y'(x_0e^t)x_0e^t=x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)$. Here one can see that the effect of the substitution is rather independent of $x_0$ and its sign.

Comment: +1 I think this answers the question of the substitution. I proposed in a deleted comment to try substitute $x=-e^t$ but then you have to take  log so I was a bit lost. I didn't thought about the singularity at zero that splits the domain. Nice answer. Really.

Comment: @LutzLehmann what if initial condition is not given and I am trying to find a general solution?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar : Then either the final solution formula you get for one side is also valid for the other side, which is the expected outcome, or you need to perform two solution computations, one for each sign of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The Eular equation $x^2y''+xy'+y=0~~~~(1)$ can be solved y assuming $y=x^m$ (Euler's substitution: ES), then we get $m=\pm i$, so the solution is $y=C_1 x^i + C_2 x^{-i}$ as $$x^i=e^{\ln x^i}=e^{i\ln x}= \cos(\ln x)+ i\sin(\ln x).$$ So the solution of
(1) can also be qrutten as $y=D_1 \sin \ln x+ D_2 \cos \ln x$. So so far no problem with ES.

Alternatively one can claim that $y_1=\sin \ln x, y_2=\cos \ln x $ are two linearly independent solutions of (1). However the solution of  the  in-homogeneous ODE:
$$x^2Y''+xY'+Y=f(x) ~~~~(2)$$
can be obtained by the method of variation of parameters using $y_1,y_2$.
See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: It does not actually answer my question,I am not looking for an alternative waay but for a justification of the standard one I mentioned.

Comment: Dear Kishalay,  As you say $x=e^{t}>0$ only for $t\in R$. But nothing stops us from going in for no-real (complex) domain of $t$. Finally, both $x,y$ have to be real in a physical problem but the intermediate variables (like $t$) here may be non-real. This is what is happening here.